# Rewrite URL in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: apache, symfony, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, fosuserbundle

I have a domain and a different server with a Symfony2 website. I created a proxy redirection from the domain name to the server. That's working now.

But I have a problem. When I want to login with the FOSUserBundle, I see my IP address of the server (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/login). I want to show my domain name instead.

Do I have to create an Apache2 RewriteRule or do I have to configure Symfony2? I have tried different RewriteRules, but it's not working.

Comment: it's not about symfony,it's about apache virtual hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it out, you have to add the following lines ***after*** Symfony2 RewriteRules. I placed my own rules before, and that caused the redirect loop.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule (.*) http://url.nl/$1 [L]
```

Here is more information about rewriting urls in Symfony2:
http://www.symfonylab.com/tricks-with-symfony-htaccess/

Answer (score 1):

Obviously Apache2. In Symfony you can configure only routes for controllers..

Something like that

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^121\.12\.12\.123
RewriteRule (.*) http://www. mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You will get a redirect loop, because the host is always the same IP address. I want to rewrite the url, e.g. replace the IP address with the domain name.